# How to use "zuerst", "später", "danach" and "dann" as Zeitadverbien?

Tags: sentence-structure, adverb, standard-german

I have the following sentence. I would like to know do we have any time stating what should come when among the options: *danach*, *dann* and *später* .

> Zuerst hat Holger Pietsch als Berater gearbeitet. Er war viel
>   unterwegs und hatte sehr viel Stress. Dann ist er richtig krank
>   geworden. Er hat dann ein Jahr gar nicht gearbeitet, Medikamente
>   genommen und eine Therapie gemacht. Danach hat er gewusst, was für ihn
>   wichtig

Will it be okay to replace *danach*, *dann* and *später* with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words then (*dann*) and afterwards (*danach*) have the same meaning. It doesn't matter if you use then or afterwards. In order to avoid repetitions, it will be okay to replace *danach*, *dann* and *später* with each other.

The time adverbs first (*zuerst*), later (*später*), then (*dann*) and afterwards (*danach*) often appear at the beginning of the sentence before the conjugated verb.

But please note that your quoted sentences are very short for a German reader. I'm not sure if the first `dann` means `dadurch`(through/thereby).

So, I attach the following text as a possible example only:

> Holger Pietsch hat zuerst als Berater gearbeitet, war viel unterwegs und hatte sehr viel Stress. Dadurch [*Danach*] ist er richtig krank geworden und hat dann ein Jahr gar nicht gearbeitet, Medikamente genommen und eine Therapie gemacht. Später hat er gewusst, was für ihn wichtig ist.

Comment: Good advice and example. Comma splices are abhored in English but **best style** in German. Full stops are for closing one row of thoughts in German.